# Is there a way to convert CSS into Modular CSS automatically?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a full project that I'm converting to react, I have normal CSS where not everything is a class, but there are element selectors aswell, for example:

```
button {   
    background-color: #316fbe;   
    width: 100%;  
    color:black;   
    padding: 15px;   
    margin: 10px 0px;   
    border: none;   
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 18px;   
}
```

is there a way to take a CSS file and convert all of it to modular CSS classes so I can use it in my react app? (I need them as classes for modular CSS to work so I don't have collisions)

I have many CSS files and would prefer not to do it manually.

Comment: What do you mean by "modular CSS classes"?

Comment: I have many CSS files, and I'm using React with multiple pages, but it's adding all of the CSS together so there are many collisions, I need to make unique classes, so I guess I just need to make them into unique classes

Comment: either that or just classes in general would work aswell